# Whats a difference between exporting arrow function after assigning it to variable vs export it directly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between these, as far as I know there shouldn't be any.

```
const func = () => true;

export default func;
```

vs

```
export default () => true;
```

Comment: In your first example, you can reference func in another place in the file. In the second example, you can't. For anything that imports this there is no difference.

Comment: If that is the extent of the code, there is no difference. If you have other code in your file, you can refer to `func` if necessary - that would be the only difference

Answer (score 1):

They are almost the same... the difference is that:

1. In the first example you can invoke or reference `func` anywhere within the module in the second you can't.
2. In the second example you are exporting a anonymous function, in the first you are not

However, none of these differences will affect the importation for the module, in that sense they are the same.

Comment: The second example has a named function as well, it just has a *different* name.